# Python Reading csv file with last column having variable number of values

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with the following data:

```
name, postcode, meals
John, 27133, breakfast
Mary, 90356, lunch, supper
David, 95221, breakfast, lunch, supper
```

How could I read each row as a dictionary with the last field being a list:

```
d_john = {
    'name': 'John',
    'postcode': 27133,
    'meals': ['breakfast']
}

d_mary = {
    'name': 'Mary',
    'postcode': 90356,
    'meals': ['lunch', 'supper'],
}

d_david = {
    'name': 'David',
    'postcode': 95221,
    'meals': ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'supper']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
# change data.csv to your file_path
with open("data.csv") as infile:
    next(infile)  # skip header
    for line in infile:
        name, postcode, *meals = line.strip().split(", ")
        print({"name": name, "postcode": postcode, "meals": meals})
```

**Output**

```
{'name': 'John', 'postcode': '27133', 'meals': ['breakfast']}
{'name': 'Mary', 'postcode': '90356', 'meals': ['lunch', 'supper']}
{'name': 'David', 'postcode': '95221', 'meals': ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'supper']}
```

The function [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) will move the iterator one line, effectively skipping the header. Then use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to read each value in the file, after using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for splitting.

A better alternative may be to use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
import csv

# change data.csv to your file_path
with open("data.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames=["name", "postcode"], restkey="meals", skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        print(dict(row))
```

**Output**

```
{'name': 'John', 'postcode': '27133', 'meals': ['breakfast']}
{'name': 'Mary', 'postcode': '90356', 'meals': ['lunch', 'supper']}
{'name': 'David', 'postcode': '95221', 'meals': ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'supper']}
```

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The **fieldnames** parameter is a sequence. If fieldnames is omitted, the
> values in the first row of file f will be used as the fieldnames.
> Regardless of how the fieldnames are determined, the dictionary
> preserves their original ordering.
>
> If a row has more fields than fieldnames, the remaining data is put in
> a list and stored with the fieldname specified by **restkey** (which
> defaults to None).

The explanation of `skipinitialspace=True`, can be found in the [Dialects and Formatting Parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) section, quoting for completeness:

> When True, whitespace immediately following the delimiter is ignored.
> The default is False.